# Photoswipe Integration for Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, photoswipe

I know it is not a simple question or demand. But I searched for a solution, could not find.

I want to use PhotoSwipe (http://photoswipe.com/) for my portfolio website, but I do not know how to integrate in blogger. By the way, I am using "lightGallery" now. This is the process I found, if it means something: https://khalistablog.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-to-add-light-gallery-in-blog-theme.html

And my website: http://www.ahmetvarlik.com/

Is there any guide or solution for this issue?

(I am not a coder nor developer. If this question is too much, please forgive me.)

Comment: Think of blogger as a nice pre-made birthday cake. Now think of photoswipe as vanilla. It's going to be hard to make the filling of the cake vanilla flavored.